# How to get all the posts with some tags assigned in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, tags

I need to get the list of posts that have assigned some tags in WordPress.
For example, I choose three tags, tag1, tag2, tag3. Then I need to get the posts that had assigned tag1&tag2,&tag3, the three at once.
I'm new in WordPress then could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more 
research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 <?php 
        query_posts( [
              'post_type' => 'YOURTYPE', 'tag' => 'tag1+tag2+tag3'
        ] );

        while (have_posts()) : 
              the_post(); 

              $post->post_title;

        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
 ?>
```

For a complete documentation, go here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try it